# How to change a pixel in a JPEG

Tags: c++, c, image, pixel

So I have a photo named `blank.jpg` that contains only black pixels and I want to modify some specific pixel (let's say the pixel with the coordinate `(x,y)`), from black to white. To be more specific, I have a list of pixels and I want to modify those pixels from black to white, creating an image, and exporting it to `image.jpg`. How can I do that?

Comment: Use a library or OS API to read the `.jpg`. Standard `c++` has no support for pixels or jpeg files at all.

Comment: What have you tried? What part is it that you don't understand, specifically? Asking how to do your whole project is too broad a question for this site.

Comment: This is not my entire project, it is just a small fraction of it. I use the library "graphics.h" and I can open a new window to draw something there(there is some coding behind but that's not the point) I want to save that drawing into a .jpg and my idea is to see where my white pixels are from my application change the corresponding black pixel (from a .jpg full of black pixels) into white.

Comment: ***I use the library "graphics.h"*** If you have a choice move to a more modern and supported alternative like `sdl` or `sfml`. Each of these will also have solutions to the jpeg problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `boost::gil` (Generic Image Library)

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/gil/doc/html/g_i_l_0164.html

You can also select one of the alternative libraries in this link :

https://cpp.libhunt.com/boost-gil-alternatives

Comment: This may be usefull , I first need to inspect all the commands there and see if something from there helps me . Thanks!